# How can i use string functions on an array of a string-backed enum?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2

I'm trying to concatenate an array of string-backed enums into one single string. I have the following

```
enum MyEnumType1: String {
    case Foo = "foo"
    case Bar = "bar"
}
```

and this method to retrieve a string from an array of string-backed enums.

```
func getConcatenatedStringFromArray(array: [MyEnumType1]) -> String {
    return array.joinWithSeparator(",")
}
```

I get a compile error stating an `Ambiguous reference to it's member "joinWithSeparator"`. How what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If my answer was helpful please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map your array to array of strings:

```
func getConcatenatedStringFromArray(array: [MyEnumType1]) -> String {
    return array.map { $0.rawValue }.joinWithSeparator(",")
}
```